# Displaying categories in tables

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, information-architecture, dashboard, data-display

I am designing a table for my company's dashboard. I need to show type of the data shown in the table. So far there is 6 type categories: Job ads, E-mail campaign, Display ads, Event, Referral and Headhunter. I was told to display it in the table without putting it there as a column.

This my wireframe so far. I was thinking about putting an icon but I was told it doesn't feel right with an icon and logo right next to it as it's too heavy. Anybody encountered similar problem? I am open to any suggestions.

[image: Table]

[image: Icons]

Edit: [image: Chips]

Comment: Have you considered showing the whole data type in form of a chip and showing it next to the source?

Comment: As in colored chip? I added a picture in the post if I get it right. However the text inside is too small I think. I could do just a color differentiation however it would take on cognitive memory of the user that he would have to remember color and connected type.

Comment: Try using a lighter background for the pill such as (#e0e0e0) and using a darker font color for the text (#424242). Also, no harm in increasing the font size a bit.

Comment: Do you know why you shouldn't include it as a column? Is it a coding constraint or something else?

Comment: It was taking up too much space and we decided to go for more elegant solution.

Comment: Tables seem to be a very data-heavy element to be included in a typical high level detail dashboard used to make decisions or drill down into further details. Also, I am having a little bit of trouble understanding exactly what type of information you want to display/prioritize and how you came up with the design (i.e. what is your rationale). I think it will provide some context to help me come up with some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue inside of a table.
Our solution was quite similar to [Shaz](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/107234/shaz) suggestion, except that we set the labels vertical. I gave my best to show it in your example image :)
[image: vertical table row labels]

I think this also easy to recognize by the user, but less space consuming.

Comment: Indeed less space consuming but impossible to read when a user has increased their browser text size.

Comment: I have to agree that the text is too long for this usage. It would be impossible to read also thinking about smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not to be part of a column, then it is not going to be sortable.  You could group them by Type.
So a heading with the name of the type and then the rows of that type.
It would make the sorting a bit more involved though.